# It's about to dinner

Tags: grammar

He wanted to have a bottle but it's twenty minutes to dinner.

> "It's about to dinner."
>
> "It's almost dinner."

What word should I use in the sentence above? about or almost?

Comment: "It's about to be dinner time." "We're about to have dinner." It's almost dinner time."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly not the first one. We do not use "about to" in this sense. But "it's almost dinner" would be acceptable. I think it would be understood as a shorter form of "it's almost dinnertime".

The only common situation I can think of in which one would say "about to" is when it's preceded by a form of "to be" and followed by a verb. In that case, it means the action will happen very soon.

- *It is about to rain* = *It will rain very soon*
- *He is about to go to Seattle* = *He will go to Seattle very soon*
- *It's about to be dinnertime* = *It will be dinnertime very soon*

and so on.

Comment: @1010 -  Yes, "It is about to dinner" is ungrammatical.  David Z did a good job of explaining: you can only use "is about to" with a verb, but *dinner* is not a verb.

Comment: @stangdon- Yes,you are right. unfortunately,I missed the last paragraph!!